# Chef set DocumentRoot in httpd recipe

Tags: apache, chef-infra, cookbook

Using https://community.opscode.com/cookbooks/httpd/versions/0.1.5

Does anyone know how to set DocumentRoot ? Property ?

I'm currently using

```
httpd_service "default" do
  listen_ports ['81']
  action :create
end
```

which produces

```
ServerName centos65x64
ServerRoot /etc/httpd
PidFile /var/run/httpd/httpd.pid
User apache
Group apache
Timeout 400
ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/error_log
LogLevel warn
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 5
DefaultType None
HostnameLookups off

Listen 0.0.0.0:81
Include conf.d/*.conf
Include conf.d/*.load
```

In httpd.conf, but i'm not sure exactly how to set the DocRoot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`httpd_config`](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/httpd/tree/b750d4736dddd292aaa04f228f68c74d769233c8#httpd_config) resource included in the cookbook will deploy a httpd config file from template to a `httpd` instance's config directory, to be included when `httpd` is run. You can configure your VirtualHosts or the main server from these templates as opposed to say, setting a node attribute that the cookbook picks up and generates a virtualhost for you.

This means you can create an [Erubis](http://www.kuwata-lab.com/erubis/users-guide.html) template for your VirtualHost config. There is an of such a config [in the cookbook tests](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/httpd/blob/b750d4736dddd292aaa04f228f68c74d769233c8/test/fixtures/cookbooks/hello_world/templates/default/hello.erb)...

```
<VirtualHost *:81>
    ServerAdmin mike@patel.net

    DocumentRoot /var/www
    CustomLog /var/log/apache/mike-patel-access.log combined

    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    LogLevel warn
</VirtualHost>
```